# This code seems to append characters outside allocated range

Tags: c++, c, string, malloc

I'm playing with some basic stuff of cpp. I'm new in this language... so I'm warning that my question maybe was not correctly formulated. I appreciate any help.

The thing is that after saw the example in [www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) I found my self with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  char *str;
  str = (char*) malloc(2);
  str[0] ='8';
  str[1] ='8';
  str[2] ='6';
  str[3] ='\0';
  printf ("%s\n",str);
}
```

And compiling with:

```
gcc -O0 -pedantic -Wall test2.cpp
```

(gcc version 4.7.2)

I get no errors and the output 886. Why I get no errors? Have I not passed the boundary of the allocated space?

I didn't get no errors and I got the output 886. Why no errors? Have I not passed the boundary of the allocated space?

In the case that code is ok... Why the example in the reference? 
In the other (more probable) case... What are the risks?

Thanks!

Comment: Any decent static analysis tool (e.g. cppcheck) should tell you (I think even Eclipse CDT C++ SA parser does).

Comment: Thanks. Is very far from c++? What are the main differences? How can a newbie distinguish one from the other? (With fortran I take several years to know what sintax come from each version)

Comment: The easiest clue is the use of `malloc` and `printf`. Most C++ code uses `new` and `cout`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get any errors because C and C++ don't do bounds checking. You overwrote sections of memory that you weren't using, but you got lucky and it wasn't anything important. Compare it to putting a row of nails into a wall where you know there's a stud. If you miss the stud, most of the time, you just put a hole in the plaster, but it's dangerous to keep doing it because eventually, you're going to hit one of the live wires instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have passed over the boundary of the allocated memory.

However, printf does not bother what size of a memory you have declared. All it cares is it will start from the start and continue till it finds a 0.

The case you created is an undefined behaviour. There can be some other data right after your allocated region (maybe another variable) in which case it will get corrupted. If the next part is unallocated memory you might escape without a visible problem. And if the memory right after your allocated memory belongs to another process, you will see the nice and tidy Segmentation Fault. The consequences can be even worse, so better not try this anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot! very quick answers! Great forum, great users.

Answer (score 2):

> the following can be found in comments in malloc.c of glibc:
>
> Minimum overhead per allocated chunk:   4 or 8 bytes    Each malloced
>   chunk has a hidden word of overhead holding size    and status
>   information.
>
> Minimum allocated size: 4-byte ptrs:  16 bytes    (including 4
>   overhead)
>             8-byte ptrs:  24/32 bytes (including, 4/8 overhead)
>
> When a chunk is freed, 12 (for 4byte ptrs) or 20 (for 8 byte
>   ptrs but 4 byte size) or 24 (for 8/8) additional bytes are    needed;
>   4 (8) for a trailing size field and 8 (16) bytes for    free list
>   pointers. Thus, the minimum allocatable size is    16/24/32 bytes.

Since minimum allocated size would be 16/24/32, since it is greater than 3 bytes your program ran without errors. This is one of the possibility executing your program correctly.

Comment: That is one(!) of all possible implementations - a malloc for an embedded system with tiny memory might allocate exactly the requested memory (nothing more)

Comment: @DieterLücking yes, this is one of the possible implementations, I believe he came across this kind of implementation of malloc.

Comment: Thanks. This also helps. Actually I ask for any kind of help, and always I learn.